# how to get one dimensional vector from an array in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Does anyone know how to get a real vector from one column of array in VBA?
I've done the following steps:

```
'' read one column from 2D array
Dim ixy()
ixy = Application.Index(ts.Vertices, , 1)
```

And everything was looking all right until I wanted to ReDim the vector and add one more value to the end:

```
ReDim Preserve ixy(LBound(ixy) To UBound(ixy) + 1, 1 To 1)
ixy(UBound(ixy)) = ts.Vertices(1, 1)
```

This simply doesn't work because I cant ReDim non-last dimension of array. So how to obtain a vector by reading a column from an array? In Locals window the variable `ixy` looks `+ : ixy :  : Variant(1 to 32, 1 to 1)` so it's not 1d array.

I know how to obey this with loops but just want to find clear solution with minimum code. Any suggestions?

Comment: What I wanted is `transpose`. The first `ixy = Application.Index(ts.Vertices, , 1)` remains the same and its just needed to be transposed. What a simple solution! `ixy = Application.Transpose(ixy)` Many thanks for this suggestion!

Comment: I got the parameter off, but If I remember correctly Transpose returns 2D array, and Index( , 0) 1D array

Comment: For me this first solution with zero doesn't work. But the second is great. I use Excel 2016, 64-bit if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

From the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) Remarks section:

> If you set Row_num or Column_num to 0 (zero), INDEX returns the array of values for the entire column or row, respectively.

```
ixy = Application.Index(ts.Vertices, 0, 1)
```

or

```
ixy = Application.Transpose(ts.Vertices)
```

Comment: `ixy = Application.Transpose(ixy)` works, because `ixy = Application.Transpose(ts.Vertices)` transposes whole 2d array. This first one should stay the same as: `ixy = Application.Index(ts.Vertices, , 1)` (without zero)